# How can I crack a WPA 2 PSK encrypted password?

Tags: wifi, mac-spoofing

I tried cracking a wifi password that uses WPA 2 PSK encryption. The network is using MAC filtering as a security measure. How can I crack the password of the same network?

Comment: Are you asking how to do MAC spoofing? Why do you need to spoof a MAC to crack a wifi password?

Comment: Actually the wifi network to which im trying to do this crack is using MAC filtering for its security.So specific devices whose MAC addresses are added previously can only connect to the network.So if i spoof my MAC address with MAC of a connected device,can i successfully connect to that network.Sorry,if my assumption is completely wrong.

Comment: I'm uncomfortable with this kind of question. It's asking for direct help in cracking someone's wifi network.

Comment: Its not for cracking someone's network.Its my own network.My companie's network.I have the duty to test security of wifi in  my company.Harming others is not my area of interest.

Comment: @PentestLover then I'm still confused: do you want to know how to change your MAC? Why do you need to crack the password if you can already connect? What is your question?

Comment: @schroeder : The reason for your confusion is my question itself.I agreed.Soryy for inconvinience mate.Actually, I need to pentest my companies wifi network .If i can crack/get into the network,then i can submit a successful attack scenario to the management and i can prove that security of wifi is poor.

Comment: @PentestLover: Your approach is odd. The security of a WPA2 Wifi network hinges on the WPA key, not on MAC filtering.

Comment: @pascal : Thanks for the valuable information mate.

Comment: @PentestLover if you can edit your question to make it clearer, we can look at re-opening it.

Comment: To answer your title question, there are hundreds (thousands?) of tutorials online for how to crack a wifi password. MAC filtering does not come into play.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a tool like `macchanger` :

```
ifconfig <interface> down # Take it down before messing with the address
macchanger -m xx:yy:zz:aa:bb:cc
ifconfig <interface> up
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, these are two separate things:

- in order to crack the WPA2 PSK, you just need to capture the authentication 'handshake'. One way of doing that is passively sniffing until you get what you need. Another way is to force a deauth, in order to force a node to re-authenticate - doing that will generally involve spoofing the AP or client MAC.
- once you have cracked the PSK, you will need to spoof your MAC to get around MAC-filtering.